# Classpath scanning of dependencies

Tags: java, spring

I have a 3-tier application: web-service, service-layer and domain-layer. The web service is present in a web application (WAR). The service-layer and domain-layer are two JAR projects. The dependencies are:

web-service --> service-layer --> domain-layer

In the service layer, the services are annotated with `@Service`. In the domain-layer, the DAOs are annotated with `@Repository`. The web service implementation class uses the services of the service-layer JAR, so it keeps one instance of each service which is automatically injected (`@Autowired`).

The dependencies are well defined in my POMs. When I deploy my WAR on Tomcat, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.mycompany.project.services.MyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:952)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:821)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:551)
    ... 37 more
```

I quote from one relevant part in the Spring docs:

> The scanning of classpath packages requires the presence of
>   corresponding directory entries in the classpath. When you build JARs
>   with Ant, make sure that you do not activate the files-only switch of
>   the JAR task.

I've checked and the service-layer JAR is present in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Any idea?

Thanks

---

**EDIT:** I have only one context file which is located in the web-service layer project (WAR) under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. In this context, I've enabled classpath scanning as follows:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.project" />
```

The package `com.mycompany.project` is the base package of my project, under which there are the web-service (`com.mycompany.project.server`), service-layer (`com.mycompany.project.services`) and domain-layer (`com.mycompany.project.domain`) packages.

I've solved the issue. I don't understand why what I've done was causing such an issue. Each service implements an interface that defines its public methods. In my web service implementation class, the references to the services used the implementation classes and not the interfaces. I just changed them to use the interface, and I don't get the issue anymore. Could anyone explain me what's wrong with using the services implementation classes instead of the interfaces for the autowiring?

Comment: Lots of things could be happening here. One likely possibility is that your web-layer context doesn't know anything about the service-layer context. Or you're not doing the component scan in your service-layer context. To answer these questions, you'd need to post your context file(s).

Comment: Please post the part of the spring configuration where you configure the component scan.

Comment: Also: look at the *end* of the exception report. Spring reports bean instantiation failures recursively, and the last bean in the report is the one that's the problem (it prevents instantiating any beans higher up in the report).

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer for your EDIT:

The reason why referring to the interface worked but the concrete implementation failed is probably to do with the [dynamic proxies](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/23/understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring/) that Spring creates for cases where you have your services annotated with `@Transactional` etc. What happens in such cases is that the type of your beans are not the implementation type anymore, but wrap around your impementation type. So when you have @Autowired by implementation type, it just cannot find it by type (which is the default).

Your fix is very appropriate, as a dynamic proxy continues to derive from the interfaces that you have defined for your implementation and so can inject by interface type - the reference that I have provided does a better job explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your component scanning configuration? If this is not set up correctly then Spring may not be discovering your service.

You want something like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.service.package"/>
```

**Edit:**

I think the problem is that your `@Service` annotation is on the interface rather than implementation class.

If you annotate your service implementation then your web controller can use either:

```
@Autowired
private ExampleService service;
```

or

```
@Autowired
private ExampleServiceImpl service;
```

Comment: Concerning your answer to my edit, the @Service annotation was and is placed on the implementation classes, not on the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you used `<context:component-scan base-package="your.service.package"/>`
2. check your autowired strategy is `byName` or `byType`; if `byName`, the `Service` annotation's name value should be right.
3. if problem still exist, check spring's log, it will print all found components' name, you could know the service is founded or not.

Comment: I've edited my question. I've enabled classpath scanning on the base package (which should include the package that contains my services). I don't specify a name in the service annotation but by default, Spring takes the same name but with the first letter in lowercase.